# can the point have a longer history

Tags: emacs

I often find myself in the following situation. Say I was editing a file with this contents

```
\begin{itemize}
\item
\end{itemize}

I really like http://stackoverflow.com !
```

And say the point was after the word \item. What I want to do is select http://stackoverflow.com , C-w it, and go back to \item, and yank it there. What I would do is  C-s htt and that would bring the point to the 2nd t of http, and from there I would go backwards, C-SPC on h, then select the rest of the word. Now, I would like to use something like C-x C-x to bring me back to \item, but it will instead bring me back to the h of http. Is there a command like C-x C-x which brings the point back through its history of location?

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I generally use <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd> to cycle back through the (local) mark ring.  Here's the relevant docs for `set-mark-command` (<kbd>C-SPC</kbd>):

> With prefix argument (e.g., C-u C-SPC),
>   jump to the mark, and set the mark
>   from position popped off the local
>   mark ring (this does not affect the
>   global mark ring).  Use C-x C-SPC to
>   jump to a mark popped off the global
>   mark ring (see `pop-global-mark').

*Note:* I changed the doc string to use <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> instead of <kbd>C-@</kbd>.

The relevant info page is ["The Mark Ring"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html), which points out if you have this setting:

```
(setq set-mark-command-repeat-pop t)
```

then the second/third/fourth... invocation of <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> doesn't need a <kbd>C-u</kbd> to repeat the popping action - which is very nice.

Answer (score 5):

I used to use `C-u C-SPC` a lot, but nowadays I use [goto-last-change.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/emacs/goto-last-change.el), which uses buffer's undo information to track changes (vs the mark ring).  I like it a little better, YMMV.